# Determine channel layout of .wav file

Tags: naudio

I'm reading .wav file using `WaveFileReader`. Lets say I got 3 channels. How do I know, its 2.1 (left, right, lfe) or 3.0 (left, center, right)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to this. WAV files with more than 2 channels are actually quite rare. Your best bet would be to make such a file and see what speakers each channel comes out of. But I suspect you may find trouble getting anything that can play such a file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who/what created the WAV file. In particular, what specific WAVEFORMAT structure they used and how they populated it.

[WaveFormat(Ex)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformatex) does not contain any information about the specific channel layout, only the number of channels.

[WaveFormatExtensible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-waveformatextensible) does contain a channel mask and the bits each indicate the intention of that channel.